# Retrieve two values in the same linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm starting with linqToSql and I still have some problems making my queries.

For example, I want to retrieve in the same query two values, a subset of elements, and an integer with the count of the elements. This is how I did it separately:

```
  int totalElements;
  IEnumerable<ClsTax> result;
  result = (from t in db.tax 
           select new ClsTax { Tax = t.tax1, Increase = t.increase }).Take(25);

  totalElements = (from t in db.tax 
             select new ClsTax { Tax = t.tax1, Increase = t.increase }).Count();
```

As you can see, I can't use result.count() because I used Take(25) to obtain only the firsts 25 elements, and I want to know how many elements are in the database.

Are there any way to obtain both values using only one linq query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
var all = (from t in db.tax select new ClsTax { Tax = t.tax1, Increase = t.increase });
var count = all.Count();
var result = all.Take(25);
```

bit simpler?

Comment: Yes, a bit simpler, but I want to minimize the database calls and traffic. 'All' could contain many records.

Comment: All will not contain many records. This is because of deferred execution. Download LinqPad, try running this query and look at the generate SQL. Two queries will be generated - the first will be a SELECT COUNT query and the second a SELECT TOP 25 query.

Comment: @joe: so... then it's a simple and and elegant solution at the same time. I will accept it. Thaks to you and to CodeMonkey. I will take your advide and download LinqPad.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var result = (from t in db.tax group t by t.ID into g select new { Tax = g.First().tax1, Increate = t.First().Increase, TotalElements = g.Count() });
```

Comment: I can't make it work. Could you explain me your code a little, please? I don't want a fish, I want a fishing rod! :D 

Thanks!

Comment: This code selects an anonymous class/type with all informations you need + the count of the items